# Deleting Images from Cloudinary in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have designed a user interface that consumes Cloudinary image API, how do I delete images from Cloudinary.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a single file can be done via the API with the destroy method. e.g. (Node JS):

```
cloudinary.uploader.destroy('zombie', function(result) { console.log(result) });
```

For more information: [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy_method)

---

All info copy/pasted from cloudinary support: [How can I delete an image via the API](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203465641-How-can-I-delete-an-image-via-the-API-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a signature with your api and secret from cloudinary, in order to make a delete request.

Install crypto package for creating the signature

```
npm i crypto
```

Then make a post request to cloudinary using the image public_id

```
import crypto from "crypto";

const generateSHA1 = (data: any) => {
  const hash = crypto.createHash("sha1");
  hash.update(data);
  return hash.digest("hex");
};

const generateSignature = (publicId: string, apiSecret: string | undefined) => {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  return `public_id=${publicId}&timestamp=${timestamp}${apiSecret}`;
};

const handleDelete = ({ publicId }) => {
  const cloudName = "your-cloud-name";
  const apiKey = "your-cloudinary-api";
  const apiSecret = "your-cloudinary-api-secret";  
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const signature = generateSHA1(generateSignature(publicId, apiSecret));
  const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/image/destroy`;

  axios
    .post(url, {
      public_id: publicId,
      signature: signature,
      api_key: apiKey,
      timestamp: timestamp,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Image deleted from cloudinary: ", response);      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Unable to delete image: ", error)
    });
};
```